# How can I export my Arrays in JavaScript into a CSV or Excel file on IE11?

Tags: javascript, csv, export, internet-explorer-11

Assuming I have a 2D array named Data.

I need to use IE11 for this job.

Comment: join array cells by "," and the rows by "\n", then download, then open in excel

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library to create a file: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Answer (score 1):

- convert the array to the required cvs format as a string
- convert the string to a blob
- save the blob `navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'file.cvs');`